# Python 2.7 code does not give correct answer

Tags: python

For some reason it seems like the code doesn't deduct from the right object and only adds to the receiver in my code, how can I fix this so the receiver gets the right amount added to his balance

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        self.tamout = 0


    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def transfer(self, name, c):
        self.balance -= c
        name += c
        return name

David = BankAccount(400)
John = BankAccount(200)

print "David balance is", David.balance
print "john balance is", John.balance

John.transfer(David.balance, 20)

print John.balance
print David.balance
```

The result is

```
David balance is 400
john balance is 200

180

400
```

Shouldn't the last print be 420?

Comment: `John.transfer(David.balance, 20)` How have you defined `.transfer()`? That's where the issue is.

Comment: I might be dumb but shouldnt you give the entire reciever instance to the transfer function so it actually knows who to deduct from aka `def transfer(self, reciever, c):` and then `John.transfer(David, 20)`

Comment: Thanks for the edit formating code Still cannot find out how to format code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your issue

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        self.tamout = 0


    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def transfer(self, receiver, c):
        self.balance -= c
        receiver.deposit(c)
        return receiver

if __name__ == '__main__':

    David = BankAccount(400)
    John = BankAccount(200)

    print "David balance is", David.balance
    print "john balance is", John.balance

    John.transfer(David, 20)

    print John.balance
    print David.balance
```

By using David instance and use the `deposit` method on it

Answer (score 1):

Your current transfer function receives a *copy* of the receiver's balance, not the original property.

Try this instead:

```py
    def transfer(self, name, c):
        self.balance -= c
        name.balance += c
        return name
```

```py
John.transfer(David, 20)
```

Comment: repl.it/@aravindsuresh_gh/EasygoingCooperativeMedia